# Remove and override css popover

Tags: css, antd

[image]

How I can remove auto generate CSS,  `left:` to zero for all element style POPOVER antd
because it will make responsive broken.

here is my code

```
< Popover style = {
  {
    zIndex: 9,
    left: 0
  }
}
overlayStyle = {
  {
    left: 0,
    zIndex: 9
  }
}
visible = {
  formState.baby1
}
placement = "bottom"
content = {
  content(t('homePage.babySection.week1'), t('homePage.babySection.content1'))
}
trigger = "click" > {
    !formState.baby1 ? ( <
      ButtonRed height = {
        30
      }
      width = {
        100
      }
      onClick = {
        () => updateForm("baby1")
      } > {
        t('homePage.babySection.week1')
      } < /ButtonRed>
    ) : null
  } <
  /Popover>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please give popover classname and

```
.ant-popover{
left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend never overwriting a global classname from a library